# Issues in upgrading Managed Package

Tags: apex, visualforce, appexchange, isv, beta-managed-package

We are trying to upgrade our managed package from V3.2 (Managed Release) to V4.0(Managed Beta). The installation seems to fail stating - 
**'Insufficient Privileges  You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.'**

But, a fresh install takes place successfully. We are unsure of what we are missing.

Please let us know where the permissions need to be changed.

Comment: Where are you updating it. Prod, SB?

Comment: In one of our developer orgs - similar to prod.

Comment: If it is developer org then check if you have proper permission. Also i this is recently upload package then please wait for sometime.

Comment: I am a system admin. Usually, if the package is recently uploaded, it will not let me proceed with the installation saying - 'the package does not exist'. In this case, it fails during the installation.

Comment: Hi. I am facing exact same issue with our Managed package too. I am unable to upgrade the package. Did you resolved this? If so, please let me know.